# What is the actual difference between int * and int []?

Tags: c, pointers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is array name a pointer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-array-name-a-pointer-in-c)

I passed in an `int *` variable to a function which is defined as `func(int var[])` and the compiler was complaining that passing in argument from incompatible pointer type. What's the difference, or is there no difference at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function declarations `R foo(T[])` and `R foo(T *)` are identical for all types `T`.

Your error lies somewhere else.

(You can call `foo` with either a pointer to a `T` or with the name of an array-of-`T`s, since the latter decays to a suitable pointer during the call.)

**Example:**

```
void foo(int *);
void bar(int[]);

void example(int * a)
{
    int n = 10;
    int p[] = { 1, 2, 3 };

    foo(a);     bar(a);
    foo(p);     bar(p);    // all those are OK
    foo(&n);    bar(&n);
}
```